# Axon Framework: Android support?

Tags: android, cqrs, axon

I am currently investigating CQRS libraries for my next Android application and I was wondering: does Axon Framework support Android? I know from the documentation that it uses annotations and I am curious whether someone has experience with how this would be integrated into Android.

Thanks in advance!

Abel

Answer (score 1):

The only topic in the mailing list which touches on mobile (not specifically Android) is this **["Using axonframework / event sourcing for offline synchronisation"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/axonframework/9cGiqTXG_IE/0a-3cp0vbY8J)**.

I'm new to Axon as well. What I already captured is that you would probably like to use mobile app as simple Axon-***un***aware client to your backend. Current 2.4.3 version of Axon provides out of the box implementations for distribution of Commands over JGroups and distribution of Events over RabbitMQ. Others can be added easily, but it will add to your learning curve. Both of these distribution implementations are more backend-oriented (your mobile devices would be an odd choice for JGroups cluster, for example).

Moreover, I guess the use case for Axon is intentionally different (judging by low volume discussions about using it for mobile devices). For example, suppose Android clients are Axon-***un***aware in your architecture and connect to some backend using traditional web interfaces (HTTP - REST, web services, etc.). The web server, in turn, processes incoming requests from the mobile clients and translates them into Commands sent by Axon to relevant aggregates. In terms of CQRS/ES, the web server in relation to the aggregates is simply a view (on the aggregates state). The view updates itself as the result of Events from aggregates it subscribes to. In other words, the server managing this view is able to send Commands to aggregates (in "hope" of successful processing which results in new incoming Events) updating its view indirectly.

Comment: AxonFramework is primarily intended for large-scale (server side) applications. Using it in a mobile application is, in my opinion, overkill.

In a few (rare) cases, it is being used for client applications on eventually connected clients, but these applications are larger than most mobile applications.